# I'm having an issue with the following code and haven't been able to debug it

Tags: java

Error says something about `eZip` not being recognized or something

```
public class Address
{     
   private String name;
   private String street;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String zip;

   public Address(String aName, String aStreet,
         String aCity, String aState, String aZip)
   {  
      name = aName;
      street = aStreet;
      city = aCity;
      state = aState;
      zip = eZip;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Get an [IDE](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=java+IDE&oq=java+IDE), it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

um, perhaps it is because the parameter you gave is called `aZip` and eZip is not something you've made anywhere else I'm assuming.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring the constructor parameter

```
...String **aZip**)
```

And then referencing at the bottom of your constructor

```
zip = **eZip**;
```

You just misstyped, that's all.